# Python (Django) - Authenticate returning None

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm using Django's authenticate function to let users register (create an account) and sign in (login after creating an account). Authenticate works fine for registration, but when I try signing the user in after logging out, it doesn't work.

Registration Method:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
     form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
               form.save()
               username = form.cleaned_data['username']
               raw_password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
               user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password) #returns user object
               login(request, user) #works
```

Sign in Method:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
     form = AuthenticationForm(request=request, data=request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
               username = form.cleaned_data['username']
               password = form.cleaned_data['password']
               user = authenticate(user=username, password=password) #returns None              
               login(request, user) #doesn't work
```

I looked at a few other threads that reported a similar issue and added the following code to my settings.py file. However, authenticate still returns none when I try signing in.

settings.py code

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) for `authenticate` method, the valid keyword arguments are `username` and `password`. Thus, I would recommend changing the following in "Sign In" method:

`user = authenticate(user=username, password=password)`

to

`user = authenticate(request=request, username=username, password=password)`